# File System and Mount Point

Tags: mount, filesystem, files, system

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 7. The Partition that Ubuntu picked up on and tried to install on, wasn't big enough. I created a new partition but I need the File System that Ubuntu runs on, and the Mount Point.

Answer (score 0):

you should choose: `EXT4` file system, and `/` as a mount point. More details: [HowToPartition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)